# Django: Move calculations query set, away from Python code

Tags: python, django

In the following code snippet, my goal is to get **outstanding_event_total_gross**.

To get that I first lookup for each ticket that belongs to the event the amount of **sold_tickets**. Out of that, I can calculate **tickets_left**. For each ticket I then calculate the **outstanding_ticket_total_gross** which I add up to **outstanding_event_total_gross**.

A lot of the business logic happens in Python, but I wonder now if there is a more efficient query set to achieve what I am doing while calling the data from the database?

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(event=3)
outstanding_event_total_gross = 0
for ticket in tickets:
    sold_tickets = ticket.attendees.filter(
        canceled=False,
        order__status__in=(
            OrderStatus.PAID,
            OrderStatus.PENDING,
            OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
            OrderStatus.FREE,
        ),
    ).count()
    tickets_left = ticket.quantity - sold_tickets
    outstanding_ticket_total_gross = tickets_left * ticket.price_gross
    outstanding_event_total_gross += outstanding_ticket_total_gross
print(outstanding_event_total_gross)
```

Here a part of the models. I simplified them for better readability.

```
class Ticket(TimeStampedModel):
    event = models.ForeignKey()
    price_gross = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Order(AbstractTransaction, LogMixin):
    event = models.ForeignKey()
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=18, choices=OrderStatus.CHOICES, verbose_name=_("Status")
    )
    total_gross = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Comment: Can you show your models?

Comment: Sure, I added them

Comment: Sure you could do aggregate queries, but this looks pretty nice to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try like this with help of [**`conditional aggregation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation):

```
from django.db.models import Q, Count, Sum

tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(event=3).annotate(
    sold_tickets=Count(
        'attendees',
        filter=Q(
            attendees__canceled=False,
            attendees__order__status__in=(
                OrderStatus.PAID,
                OrderStatus.PENDING,
                OrderStatus.PARTIALLY_REFUNDED,
                OrderStatus.FREE,
            )
        ),
        distinct=True
    )
).annotate(
    tickets_left=F('quantity')-F('sold_tickets')
).annotate(
    outstanding_gross=F('tickets_left') * F('price_gross')
)

outstanding_event_total_gross = tickets.aggregate(total=Sum('outstanding_gross'))['total']
```

Comment: Hi ruddra, thank you for the help. I am currently running into the following issue: `"django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'canceled' into field. Choices are: attendees, created, [...]"`

Canceled is a field within the *Attendees model*. In my code above I access attendees, here however it seems to only access the *Ticket model*. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It seems like with `attendees__cancelled` and `attendees__order__status__in ` I can access it and it's counting. In general, do you think that approach with aggregation is better than calculating it in Python? I am back and forth because it also seems more complex with aggregation.

Comment: its much better to do it with aggregation, in that way DB is doing all the heavy lifting and DB hits also reduced. You can also monitor the DB hits with tools like https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/ and see the performance.

Comment: I just have one more question about `distinct=True`. I get the same results with or without. Is there a reason you explicitly set that? Or was it more for precaution?

Comment: And my last question. I was looking into `Complex lookups with Q objects` where it says it can be used for `queries with OR statements`. I just don't understand the reason we need it here because it's not an `OR` statement where you use it?

Comment: no, you can do OR operation like this `Q(Q(abc=123)|Q(cdf=456))`. You need to use pipe symbol (`|`) for doing or operation. Also regarding `distinct=True` please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations